# How to add multiple components to Android Layout

Tags: android, layout

I am creating an application that needs to draw an undirected graph where each node represents a residue in a Carbohydrate molecule (not important). The number and connectivity of the nodes is only determined at runtime.

My problem is that carbohydrates are often really big and there is only so much screen space, hence I need to be able to allow users to pan across the graph when it overflows off the screen. What is the correct way to implement it so that nodes can be added off screen?

I am currently drawing the nodes onto a Canvas which is contained in a FrameLayout, which after creating my custom View class I can pan and zoom, but this does not allow me to draw nodes that fall outside of the FrameLayout's dimensions. I could set the FrameLayout to be really big, but I want to prevent the user from scrolling right to the edges of the FrameLayout since this would be frustrating to the user. My preferred method would be to create a new subclass of View for each node and connection and add them to the FrameLayout, however am unsure if this is possible/how to do it?

Comment: I've been googling around and found this thing that may be usefull http://www.graphviz.org/category/tags/android

Comment: But... Take a look to a game dev lib such as http://www.andengine.org moat of the display problems are solved through them

Comment: Thanks @eduyayo, I'll have a look. EDIT: Since the application is already rather big I would prefer to stray away from libraries, but they may have some implementation details that are relevant, so thank you :)